# Why does the extra $.1$ make $\int \frac{\left(x^2+2.1x\right)}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}dx$ much harder?

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions, substitution

I'm a first-time Calc I student currently struggling in class. Yesterday we started on Substitution and Integration with integrals. One problem our professor put on the board was:

$$\int \frac{\left(x^2+2.1x\right)}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}dx$$

And he refused to solve it, said nobody in the room would be able to, and that he himself (a Ph.D) had no idea where to start solving it. However, just before that question, we had one that was almost entirely identical except for a decimal point:

$$\int \frac{\left(x^2+2x\right)}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}dx$$

with $u = x^3+3x^2+12$

and $du = (3x^2+6x)dx$

Eventually, we got to the answer of $\frac{-1}{15\left(x^3+3x^2+12\right)^5}+C$ (if anyone wants me to edit in the complete steps of the answer, please let me know).

So my question is: why does the small decimal of .1 make the otherwise-identical problem so much harder to complete, when really, the difference is a relatively tiny amount? Was our professor exaggerating?

Comment: It happens fairly often that a minor modification changes an easy integral to one that cannot be handled using elementary functions. But the integral you mention is doable, merely very very  unpleasant.  The first step is to find the real root of the cubic.

Comment: As an example of an integral that is *actually* impossible, compare the problems
$$
\int (x+1)e^{x^2 + 2x + 1}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int (x+1.1)e^{x^2 + 2x + 1}\,dx
$$

Comment: When you're finding the *exact* solution, it doesn't matter how *small* the change in the original problem is.

Comment: the primitive function Looks terrible

Comment: The derivative of $x^3+3x^2+12$ is $x^2+2x$, sparing a factor of $3$. The u-substitution exploits this very fact. However, what can you say about $x^3+3x^2+12$ and $x^2+2.1x$? Here, the integration process must involve other, less straightforward methods.

Answer (score 5):

If you like, you can think about it as follows:
$$
\int \frac{x^2+2.1x}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}dx
   = \int \frac{x^2+2x}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}dx
   + 0.1 \int \frac{x dx}{\left(x^3+3x+12\right)^6}
$$
the left integral is easy, and the right is the extra added part by your $0.1$ addition. The only difference is whether you can take it or not...